# Paired Sample T-Test for a 1-10 pain scale?

Tags: statistics

Currently looking at data in which each participant recorded their level of pain from 1-10 in terms of severity for both pre and post operation, for 3 different treatments. Such as the table below, except i have 100 participants. What kind of test(s) should i use here to see if there are differences between the effectiveness of treatments?

I thought about doing the following: Independent t tests to see if there are any differences between the treatments in post pain rating. And then paired sample t tests within each treatment condition to see if those had an effect on pain. Or possibly some type of repeated measures anova?

| ID | Pre | Post | Treatment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 4 | VR |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | VR |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | Music |
| 4 | 6 | 8 | None |

Comment: I am thinking your question would be better if it was posted on the stack exchange for Cross Validated.

Comment: Agreed; MSE isn't the best place for this.